# Conditionally color a single bar in Plotly with R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Consider the following shiny app:

**UI**

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Random Number Generator"),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("random_numbers")
      )
)
```

**SERVER**

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  df <- reactive({
    runif(100)
  })

  output$random_numbers <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly() %>%  
      add_trace(y = sort(df()),
                type = 'bar',
                name = 'Random Numbers',
                marker = list(color = 'green')) %>%
      add_trace(y = mean(df()),
                type = 'bar',
                name = 'Mean',
                marker = list(color = 'orange'))
    })
}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: sample graph]

**QUESTION**

Is there a way I can display the mean on the same trace in the same order as the other runif(100) so that I can keep the ascending order AND keep the average a different color? I want it to look like the following graph:

[image: what it should look like]

Answer (score 1):

There is an argument `x` you can use. To that one you can pass the value of the index that is closest to the sorted array. In your case: `x = which.min(abs(sort(df()) - mean(df())))`.

The full app:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Random Number Generator"),
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("random_numbers")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  df <- reactive({
    runif(100)
  })

  output$random_numbers <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly() %>%  
      add_trace(
        x = 1:100,
        y = sort(df()),
                type = 'bar',
                name = 'Random Numbers',
                marker = list(color = 'green')) %>%
      add_trace(
        x = which.min(abs(sort(df()) - mean(df()))),
        y = mean(df()),
                type = 'bar',
                name = 'Mean',
                marker = list(color = 'orange'))
  })
}


runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Edit: The more code intensive but correct solution can be found below.

```
  output$random_numbers <- renderPlotly({
    full.seq <- 1:(length(df()) + 1)
    mean.idx <- which.min(abs(sort(df()) - mean(df())))
    if((sort(df()) - mean(df()))[mean.idx] < 0) mean.idx <- mean.idx + 1 
    rand.seq <- full.seq[-mean.idx]

    plot_ly() %>%  
      add_trace(
        x = rand.seq,
        y = sort(df()),
        type = 'bar',
        name = 'Random Numbers',
        marker = list(color = 'green')) %>%
      add_trace(
        x = mean.idx,
        y = mean(df()),
        type = 'bar',
        name = 'Mean',
        marker = list(color = 'orange'))
  })
```

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: the race is still on since there is a mistake in it :D

Comment: Yeah, but I have work to do - so it is all yours. Didn't know you did plotly :)

Comment: The edit to this answer is very close to what I need. However, the average is 1 bar out of place when I use the code. EDIT: It seems that this does not happen every time but can sometimes happen.

Comment: yes thats what i mentioned before. it depended on whether the value the closest to the mean was higher or lower than the mean. I made an edit, its a bit more code intensive, but in the end the correct solution